# Binding <li> items to dock elements by id

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a `<ul>` with `A` and `B` as its `<li>` that has a highlight on hover effect. I also was able to create a Mac OS X like dock (inspired by [Henrique Erzinger's CodePen](https://codepen.io/herzinger/pen/khfwI)) with items `A1`, `A2`, `A3`, `B1` and `B2`.

Is there a way to items in list with items in the dock, so that hovering on a list item brings the linked dock elements in focus?

For example:

```
Hover A -> Focus/Enlarged A1, A2, A3
Hover B -> Focus/Enlarged B1, B2
```

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ssinhaonline/v2gaox78/61/) with the list and dock included.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with JavaScript. You will have to group your dock items with classes, for example .`groupA` and `.groupB`, and give them a sub class `.focused` (so `.groupA.focused`) which should have the same styling as your `:hover` style for the dock elements do now.

Your script should then trigger when you hover over A or B and respectively toggle the .focused class on your dock elements.

That's the theory at least. The coding you will have to do yourself.